# entire webpage flicker/fade in/out randomly

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for I guess a javascript that will make the entire webpage flicker/fade out/in randomly. As if the viewing an old tv screen and they would flicker out sometimes.

Found this on jquery, but it wont flicker an entire webpage..

```
var p = $("p");

p.blinker({
    timeHidden: 50,
    intervalRangeStart: 100,
    intervalRangeStop: 5000
});

p.bind({
    // pause blinking on mouseenter
    mouseenter: function(){
        $(this).data("blinker").pause();
    },
    // resume blinking on mouseleave
    mouseleave: function(){
        $(this).data("blinker").blinkagain();
    }
});
```

Any ideas? Or is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery has plenty of options to change the opacity of elements.  Just use these with `setTimeout()` with the timeout period generated by `Math.random()` to get the timing you want.

http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/

Comment: yeah, I've never worked with java to even begin to know. But after viewing one of the other answers, it's more like a flickering neon sign type thing I'm looking for. Would the fade thing work for something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Both of these look promising from codepen.io.

```
/lbebber/pen/XJRdrV
/Prashantsani/pen/FhgzA
```

This system prevents a direct link and I'm not going to copy someone else's code and paste it here as if I had written it.

Comment: yeah, thanks for those. I'm trying to browse the codepen site, but it keeps locking up my laptop? But it's more like the flickering neon signs they have, but for the whole page to flicker. I didn't think that was possible with css. That's crazy! I love css more and more everyday. Probably trying to load to many effects at once is what caused firefox to stop responding.

Comment: I think that one example with the "TV" turning on and off would be cool to try full page myself.